# How to activate virtualenv in Cygwin after copying the virtualenv folder

Tags: python, shell, cygwin, virtualenv

complete beginner here. Trying to build a flask web app. Using Windows 8.

Having some problems activating my python virtualenv in Cygwin. I have been using git shell up till now with no problems.

I copied my folder ("app") into my cygwin home directory and it is set up like so:

```
app - templates
    - static
    - flask - env - scripts - python
                  - ...
    - hello.py
    - ...
```

I change directory into the app folder, then when I type the command to activate my virtualenv:

```
$ source flask/env/scripts/activate
```

The terminal shows:

```
(env)
```

so I assume that it is working, until I double check which python:

```
$ which python
```

and that returns my original global python install, not the virtual environment. I've checked the installed packages to double check which python environment I am using.

I use the same command in git shell and it activates the right virtualenv. Where am I going wrong / what do I need to change? Please let me know if you need any more information.

I created a new virtual environment using cygwin and when I activated the new env, it switched to that environment fine. Why won't it work for the folder which I copied in?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I created a new virtual environment using cygwin and when I activated the new env, it switched to that environment fine. **Why won't it work for the folder which I copied in?**

This last sentence is the real problem. The way you try to activate is correct. The problem is that the `virtualenv` directory must not be moved.

The `activate` script inside the `virtualenv` uses absolute paths internally. If you move the directory, the paths will no longer work, and so `which python` finds the first valid binary on `PATH`, which is your global binary.

If you need to move the project to a different location, and the virtualenv together with it, then recreate the virtualenv, do not copy it.
The recommended practice is to have a `requirements.txt` file, and install packages using `pip install -r requirements.txt`.
That way, recreating a virtualenv is very easy: create an empty virtualenv, and run the `pip ...` command. There should be nothing else inside the virtualenv that needs moving, only what `pip` put there, or other python installer scripts, if you used any (and which you would need to re-run, in addition to `pip`).

Comment: This does not answer the question in the title, but I keep coming back to it because it has very good SEO.

Comment: @Grault It's the question title that was misleading. I fixed that now. Thanks for pointing it out.